# Tabbar reloads after Orientation Change

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I´m currently working on an Tab based iOS Application. The App should work in Landscape and Portrait. Now on every Orientation Change the Tabbar is reloaded and the first TabbarItem is selected. Does anybody has some similar behavior and knows how to fix it?

Comment: That's clearly not designed behavior. Are you running code on rotation / size change? Are you using a subclassed `UITabBarController`?

Comment: yes i use an subclassed UITabBarController, i run no code on rotation change.